SSR data on onclick in Next.js
Is there is any way to get data from SSR while using onclick functionality.
"use client";

const TestForCard = () => {

  const navigateToOther = (item: any) => {
      const response = await fetch(api/Path,
       {
        method: "POST",
       }
     );
  };

  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data, "data");

  return (
    <>
      <h1 onClick={() => navigateToOther("hii")}>Click Me</h1>
    </>
  );
};
export default TestForCard;

While my server Side file is this ,but the data which is received is client side in Client Side file is there is any way to get data from SSR while my parent should be client?
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const POST = async (req, { params }) => {

const data = await fetch(URL);
const response = await data.json();

 return NextResponse.json({
   response
  });

}



If you want the navigateToOther function to run server-side instead of client-side, make the first line of the function body "use server" and it will become a React Server Action. You can also create a file with the "use server" directive at the top that exports the function, and then it can be imported and called in any client component. If that's not what you want, please explain what "get data from SSR" means. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations
